# Вызов новой функции из подключаемого .js файла

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! Часть страницы админки приходится обновлять посредством ajax, в том числе бывает, что добавляются новые функции javascript при таком обновлении. Но почему-то попытки их вызвать приводят к ошибке undefined. Если эти же функции прописать сразу в код страницы, то они вызываются нормально. Но функции надо формировать динамически. Не подскажете, что можно сделать, чтобы они вызывались?

Comment: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml не поможет?

Comment: такой подход неприемлем, лучше так ни делать никогда (даже с помощью примочек выше ссылкой указанных), старайтесь загружать все ваши `js`-приключения в `head` страницы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Но почему-то попытки их вызвать
> приводят к ошибке undefined. Если эти
> же функции прописать сразу в код
> страницы, то они вызываются нормально.

Здесь может только и только одна проблема - **ОБЛАСТЬ ВИДИМОСТИ**.

**Если эти функции прописать в код** - скорее всего вы прописываете их в ту же область видимость и следовательно они будут доступны оттуда на прямую.

"Чтобы они вызывались", нужно прежде всего:

1) Убедится на все 100% что файл который подключается "динамически", дейтсвительно подключился и не содержит синктаксических ошибок, которые могут вызывать фатальную отсановку скрипта.

Это просто, для этого, запишите что-нибудь в тот файл и вызовите ( = стэнд алон тест), например  вот так:

**Файл: test.js**

```
alert('OK. Works');
// все остальное.... внизу
```

**Основной файл:**

```
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

Если после включения выведет алерт, то значит проблем с подключением скрипта не было. Если не выведет - то вы все правильно поняли - не может по каким-то причинам подключить скрипт.

> Но функции надо формировать
> динамически.

Если под "формировать" вы имеете ввиду создавать, а не подключать, то это просто **УЖАС**. И если это все еще генерируется через серверный язык... О_о

Предназначения функций/классов нужно строго разделять. Одна функция не должна делать/знать много, она должна **выполнять** конкретно ОДНУ поставленную задачу.

Золотое правило хорошего кода

- Не миксуйте JavaScript с HTML
- Не миксуйте JavaScript c серверным языком, таким так PHP, Python итд

На заметку:

Подобные проблемы (с областью видимости в том числе) будут возникать и в дальшейнем, до тех пор пока вы не:

- Почитаете что такое `SOLID` принципы
- `MVC/Dependecy Injection` (P.S это также касается JS, не только PHP)

В хорошо оформленном веб-приложении передача данных происходит, не "создаванием" динамически, а передачей переменных через `XML/JSON` посредством `AJAX`.

**Возращаясь к вопросу**

Посколько в вопросе нет примеров/сэмлов кода, то придется отвечать аналогично - догадываясь в предположениях.

1) Протестируйте что файл действительно включается

2) Убедитесь что эти функции - они глобальные, а не приватные методы класса.

Comment: спасибо большое всем за ответы, просто в JS разбираюсь плоховато, на странице есть порядка 10-ти списков с возможностью перетаскивания, эти списки иногда обновляются аяксом, т.е. вся страница не перезагружается, а только список, и вот подключение плагина для перетаскивания выполняется след. кодом, кот. у меня расположен в тексте страницы рядом с каждым списком:
$("#all_packages_ul_1").dragsort({ dragSelector: "div", dragEnd: saveOrder_packages_1, placeHolderTemplate: "<li class='placeHolder'><div></div></li>" });
вместо цифры один только дальше идут цифры до 10 для каждого списка

Comment: в этом куске кода указывается название функции, кот. должна отрабатывать при окончании перетаскивания, и дело в том, что я не знаю, как в этом случае, при такой записи, передать ей параметры, поэтому далее каждый раз формирую свою js функцию-обработчик для каждого списка, т.е. это у меня, например, если 5 списков, то будут функции saveOrder_packages_1(),saveOrder_packages_2(),...saveOrder_packages_5()

Comment: Но даже эта неправильная система не работает после ajax добавления нового списка, например, 6-го, в коде появляется код функции saveOrder_packages_6(), но вызвать её невозможно, хотя код этой функции правильный, и если его прописать сразу, а не ajax, то всё работает. Я сама сразу понимала, что неправильно делаю, просто не хватало пока времени разобраться.

Comment: все файлы, конечно, подключаются, в отладчике код из подключаемого js-файла вылетает с ошибкой undefined function на той строчке, в кот. пытается вызвать эту новую, прописанную в код страницы средствами ajax функцию. Аналогичные, почти ничем не отличающиеся функции, существовавшие в коде страницы сразу, а не вставленные скриптом позже, вызываются нормально.

Comment: подключите все ваши `javascript` файлы в начале страницы, т.е. если у вас есть файл `test.js`, то подключать его нужно см. ответ.

Answer (score -3):

Смотрите внимательно.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     </body>
 </html>
```